# ValueError: time data 'Oct 5, 2020' does not match format '%b %d,%Y'

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to convert this string to another format of a date.

```
def dateCorrect(last_modified_date):
    if last_modified_date is not None:
       last_modified_date = datetime.strptime(last_modified_date, '%b %d,%Y')
       date = last_modified_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
       print(date)
       print(type(date))
```

`dateCorrect("Oct 5, 2020")`

if gives error:
ValueError: time data 'Oct 5, 2020' does not match format '%b %d,%Y'

I also tried :

```
last_modified_date = datetime.strptime(last_modified_date, '%b-%d-%Y')
```

> this also does not work.  I want to change it to a date having the
> "%Y-%m-%d" format.

Answer (score 4):

You get this error because you're missing a space in your format -- it should be '%b %d, %Y'. With this fix, your code works fine.

Comment: Yep, the bigger the headache, the smaller the cause, IME.